# Show that a paraboloid is asurface .

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

[image]

That I know about paraboloid is all in the picture.

I wrote its surface patch. (Hopefully, it is correct)

From there, what do I need to do in order show that a paraboloid is a surface.

---

Definition of a surface: S in $\Bbb R^3$ isa surface if every point $p \in S$ admits an open sets W, $p \in W$ and a homemorphism $\phi :U\to W\cup S$ For U is an open set in $\Bbb R^2$

---

Note that these surface examples are in my notebook. I am asking these in order to understand better. These are not homework or else. Just for learning better. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Why downvote? I wrote what I know. And ıt is a proper question.

Comment: Did you tried something? Has any guess about some parametrisation for the paraboloid?

Comment: Yes I wrote its parametrization in the picture. Please look at the picture. Dear @Tomás

Comment: $(u,v,u^2+v^2)$ is its parametrization. @Tomás

Comment: Please can you help me Dear @Tomás

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can prove that $\sigma $ is a homeomorphism we are done.

Hint: Let $\pi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a canonical projection, i.e. $$\pi(x,y,z)=(x,y)$$

Note that $\pi(u,v,u^2+v^2)=(u,v)$ hence, if we restrict $\pi$ to $S$ then, $\sigma^{-1}=\pi: S\to\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now, it remains to show that $\pi$ restricted to $S$ is continuous.

Comment: in order to Show that $\sigma $ is homeomophic, $\sigma$ is 1-1 continuous and its inverse continuous. But I cannot conclude properly. I want to learn perfectly. Thus, can you Show more? :)

Comment: Could you conclude something with the hint hat I gave you?

Comment: okay, first of all, since $(u,v,u^2+v^2)$ is polynomial, this is continious.

Comment: seconly, for 1-1ness, let $\sigma(u,v)=\sigma(m,n)$. Then $u=m$ and $v=n$ So this is 1-1.

Comment: thirdly, i need to show its inverse. but i dont know how to find such a function's inverse. :( can you help? hopefully, previous ones are correct.

Comment: With my hint I have showed to you what is the inverse of $\sigma$.

Comment: hmmm... Then, the inverse of $(u,v,u^2+v^2)$ is $(u,v)$. Isnt it?

Comment: Think geometrically. You are parametrizing the paraboloide with the plane and in this case, you can see the paraboloid above the plane. Now, what is the most natural function that sends the points of the paraboloid into the plane?

Comment: Its something like a lamp. If you turn on a lamp above the paraboloid, its shadow will be a plane. Can you see it?

Comment: I am thinking, but sorry nope. :(

Comment: I am learning these by myself. So I am not good enough

Comment: Ok, let me add some more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are so helpful:)

Comment: That's $a$ be a point on the plane. Then $\sigma^{-1}=(\sqrt{a-v^2}, (v-a))$

Comment: Take any point on $S$. This point can be written in the form $(u,v,u^2+v^2)$ for $u,v\in\mathbb{R}$. Now apply $\pi$ to this point. You get that $\pi(u,v,u^2+v^2)=(u,v)$ or equivalenlty $$\pi(\sigma(u,v))=(u,v)$$ The last equality is the definition of inverse function.

Comment: Okay I see. THanks. :)))